# Statistic to take account of sensitivity of temperature values

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, mean, descriptive-statistics

I have a unique problem. I am looking to quantify the difference between two temperature value of different components.

I am looking at three statistic to see that difference

- **Absolute mean difference of two component A1 and A2**
- **Absolute mean difference/ Mean of component A1**
- **Z- Score = Absolute mean difference / Standard deviation of one of the component.**

My goal is that I have to make a decision if two values are statistically different. However, I cannot rely just on all three statistics separately for that Because of following reasons.

1. **Z-Score** : if my temperature fluctuation through out the data is very low(sigma close to zero). then for even a absolute mean difference of temp values, the z-score will be very high. However in reality  this should be ignored because this small temperature variation can happen because of any reasons.
2. **Absolute mean difference:** For some components in my data, temperature can range from 40-50 deg C , while for some other components it can go to 400-500 deg C. However a 10 deg difference between components ranging 40-50 deg C might be significant but not for component temp ranging in 400-500 deg C.
3. **Absolute mean difference/ Mean of component A1:** Again here, the problem is similar as z-score statistic. if the absolute mean values of teo components are in lower ranges , then for even small deviations, the ratio will be large.

**Finally, My question is: Is there any other statistic available to solve my issue here? If not, then is there a way I can create a score kind of thing with combination of above three statistics.**

PS: I have tried couple of combination of above statistics to create the score but nothing is working yet.
Will converting one of the statistic to a logarithmic values will help?

Comment: I'd be reluctant to have as your goal "to make a decision if two values are statistically different." Statistical significance and practical significance can be very different. Please say more about why you are doing this. You might need to have completely different models for the components that are typically at 40-50 C versus those that are typically at 400-500 C. Why do you feel that you need a single model to cover all of the components?

Comment: The reason I am looking at a single model is because in reality, I have 60-70 different sensors ranging from temperature, voltage, pressure, flow and other things.

I am open to different model for different sensors. However, list of sensors changes with different machines and  project. So creating a model based on sensors would be difficult. I will edit the question to explain the issue more clearly.

Comment: So why do you expect that the very same type of statistic will be useful for all of those different types of sensors? Please say more about the practical problem that you are trying to solve, how you intend to use and combine the information about the 60-70 different sensors, what types of decisions you might be making based on the analysis. Please provide that information by editing the question, as information in comments can be hard to find and sometimes gets lost. Again, please focus on the practical significance first, then we can deal with statistical significance as needed.